# utf-8 cannot insert to mysql after connection to mssql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

first of all , I connected two database -mssql & mysql- .

```
 global $link,$link_voip;
    $link = mssql_connect('A', 'B', 'C');
    mssql_select_db('D', $link);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
    }
    $link_voip = mysql_connect('E','F','G') or die("err");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $link_voip);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $link_voip);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'", $link_voip);
mysql_select_db('voip', $link_voip);
```

I want to **update** a row on mysql database with mssql's information:
I get information correctly , but  **mysql database cannot insert utf-8** (persian language).

I'm working with **phpmyadmin** ,I used to try:
1- change collation to utf_general_ci 
2- add

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $link_voip);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $link_voip);
```

before query.
3-add N before variable that may be changed.

```
    $q="UPDATE cc_card SET  firstname=N'$fname' , lastname=N'$lname',phone='$phone',credit='$credit' 
    WHERE id='$id'";
```

but still it doesn't work.

Comment: What are your table definitions? Are those unicode or 8bit? And what type of tables, so what storing engine do you use inside mysql?

Comment: Also, is the data you get from mssql really unicode? Have you checked that? How?

Comment: they are unicode & MyISAM engine

Comment: yes, i already have checked data with print on information

Comment: That does not really say what encoding you received. I learned to be paranoid about encoding when MS-Windows systems are involved. Maybe you could check with a hexeditor? Also, have you tried inserting the same values from a manually typed statement? Any difference?

Comment: I also can insert query in SQL section in phpmyadmin manually and it accept utf-8

Comment: Then most likely there is a difference in the statements. They might look the same, but can have different encoding. I suggest you dump both into separate files (printing does not prove anything) and use a hexeditor to look inside on a byte level. You can compare the sequences. I bet there is a difference.

Comment: Thank you ,How to test mssql field with hex editor? and if there is a difference between mssql output and my insert sequence , how to fix it?

Comment: You cannot really "fix" that afterwards. You have to fix the issue where it occurs. So whilst retrieving the data from mssql. How to test? I wrote that twice: dump into file and use a hexeditor. Any problems with that?

Comment: Oh, another thing: what is the actually error message you get? "Does not work" is pretty meaningless. What error do you really get? Not, that this is a simple write permission problem with the account you are using!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- in **mssql** :
   1-1. check table type is nvarchar
   1-2. convert to varbinary (CONVERT(varbinary(MAX),tblname) 
 
           1-3. use [bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) 
  1-3. use [chr(hexdec$varibale)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) 
 
           1-5. use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) 
2- in **mysql**:
use N before variable for update/insert in database